# Powershell Script won't run correctly in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line, scripting

I recently created some PowerShell code that runs perfectly fine on its own or via a command prompt (or a .bat file). Hell, it runs fine as a .cmd file too. When I create a task scheduler task for it to run automatically, the result claims that the job runs 'successfully' but there isn't any output in the folder destination.

The whole goal of the script is to look at a particular subfolder within outlook and find files with a particular name. Then it outputs the latest related attachments to a specific destination.

**PowerShell Script**

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\Spreadsheets"
$ol = New-Object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $ol.GetNamespace("MAPI");
$acct = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$targetfolder = $acct.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Training" }
$targetfolder.Items | foreach {
    if ($_.ReceivedTime -ge $limit) { 
            $_.attachments |
            foreach {
                Write-Host "attached file: ",$_.filename
                If ($_.filename -match 'SessionCompletions' -or $_.filename -match 'Certifications'){
                    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $_.FileName))
                    $ol.quit()
                } 
            } 
    }
}
```

I've tried all kinds of things to get the Task within Task Scheduler to work and nothing so far seems to help. To start I tried using a basic bat file to run the task. Mind you, this basic format has worked with many other PowerShell related tasks that I set up to run via a bat file.

**Basic Bat Script**

```
powershell -file extract-spreadsheets.ps1
```

Now sometimes I've needed to include an -executionpolicy argument as well but it sadly didn't work in this case.

**A little more complex Script**

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -File  "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\extract spreadsheets.ps1"
```

Note: I made sure the get-executionpolicy on the computer was / is set to **RemoteSigned**. I've also tried **Unrestricted** as well.

I've also tried even more complex / different approaches such as . . .

**Even more Complex of a Script**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=C:\Scripts\David attachment Project\
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%extract-spreadsheets.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

And I've even tried getting a .cmd file going and trying to use that within Task Scheduler:

```
@@:: This prolog allows a PowerShell script to be embedded in a .CMD file.
@@:: Any non-PowerShell content must be preceeded by "@@"
@@setlocal
@@set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%*
@@if defined POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS:"=\"%
@@PowerShell -Command Invoke-Expression $('$args=@(^&{$args} %POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS%);'+[String]::Join(';',$((Get-Content '%~f0') -notmatch '^^@@'))) & goto :EOF

$olFolderInbox = 6
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\Spreadsheets"
$ol = New-Object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $ol.GetNamespace("MAPI");
$acct = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$targetfolder = $acct.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Training" }
$targetfolder.Items | foreach {
    if ($_.ReceivedTime -ge $limit) { 
            $_.attachments |
            foreach {
                Write-Host "attached file: ",$_.filename
                If ($_.filename -match 'SessionCompletions' -or $_.filename -match 'Certifications'){
                    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $_.FileName))
                    $ol.quit()
                } 
            } 
    }
}
```

In terms of Task Scheduler, I've tried a multitude of things. To start . . .

For Program / script, I tried various relative and explicit destinations / paths for bat, cmd and PowerShell.

**Some examples:**

1. Powershell.exe (again I've also done the full path as well)
2. C:\Scripts\attachment Project\Training_Reports.bat
3. Training_Reports.bat
4. C:\Scripts\attachment Project\extract-spreadsheets.cmd

Note: I've added the above Programs / Actions with and without quotes.

Again, the more frustrating thing is the basic format of Training_Reports.bat with the **start in (optional)** field of:

`C:\Scripts\attachment Project or C:\Scripts\attachment Project\`

Has worked with every other script / task I have set up in this format!

I've tried numerous arguments for Execution Policy such as *RemoteSigned*, *Bypass* and *Unrestricted*. I've Added other arguments like: *-NoProfile, -noninteractive, -File, -command, -NoLogo* etc etc.

Examples of what the **Arguments Field** has looked like within Task Scheduler:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\extract-spreadsheets.ps1"
-NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\extract-spreadsheets.ps1"
-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "C:\Scripts\attachment Project\extract-spreadsheets.ps1"
```

I tried using various accounts to '**run the task**'.

1. my domain account (which my account is a global domain admin and has
   full permissions)
2. local Admin account
3. another Domain Admin Account
4. I've tried even SYSTEM

None of the accounts above have changed the outcome. Other settings I've looked at that people claim could mess with Tasks.

1. Turned off '*Start the task only if the computer is on AC power*'
2. Ran the task  **whether user is logged on or not**
3. Also ran it as **when user is logged on**
4. Set it for '**Highest privileges**'
5. I tried running the task in '**configure for**' drop down menu for
   **Windows 10** and **Windows 7 / Server 2008**.

Other things I have tried:

1. The initial PowerShell Script had mapped drive destinations. I changed the code to use C drive locations.
2. Explicitly giving that user account full control over the
   directories involved.
3. Changing ownership of the directories involved to the same user.
4. Changing the security permissions on the ps1, cmd, bat, outlook.exe files to always Run as Administrator.
5. Tried running the script with Outlook running and not running.
   Note: running it manually works **regardless if Outlook is running.**

Why is this task within Task Scheduler not outputting correctly?

Comment: To determine if the problem is in the scheduled task part or in the script part, I would recommend scheduling a simple script, e.g. one that writes Hello world to a text file in C:\, and see if that gets executed.

Comment: @KJ I didn't think about that. So in looking into it, Outlook is 64-bit and PowerShell is 64-bit. Permission wise, all three have the same permission set. Mostly because the computer is part of a domain. So sadly it doesn't help. One of the users i've been trying is a local admin as well as a Global Domain Admin. The Global Admin for example, has full permissions to all three applications (Task Scheduler, PowerShell and Outlook).

Comment: @Astrotrain I did as you suggested. I scheduled a bat file, to run a simple PS 'hello world' output to a text file in the same folder structure and it ran fine. I set the task to have the normal / basic structure as other scripts i've set up.

Comment: @KJ Thanks. I'll dig into the link and see what I can find. In thinking about your post more, I don't think really matter outlook wise when it comes to Task scheduler. Mostly because task scheduler would either be running the PS or bat file and THEN those two things would directly reference outlook, right? On the other  hand . . . as the other poster suggested, I created a test PS that outputs to the folder via a bat file from task Scheduler.  It ran fine.